# Using PWM to create DAC

Tags: pwm, dac, low-pass, integrator

It is my understanding that a square wave can be converted to a smooth analog signal via passive low pass filter. However, this low pass filter acts like an integrator which ideally achieves the same result.

**For the application of a DAC using PWM in the neighborhood of 1MHz, would an integrator or a low pass filter give me better results in terms of the quality of the analog output? Are there advantages/disadvantages to each method?**

Would an integrator cause issues by relying on the capabilities of the OP amp used?

Comment: *"low pass filter acts like an integrator which ideally achieves the same result"* This statement is not correct. If the PWM is outputting only zero or positive voltage, the output of the (ideal) integrator will keep increasing and will not decrease.

Comment: the low pass limits the current available to maintain the voltage level, but at 1MHz, you won't need much resistance, especially with a 2-stage. You can use a unity gain amp after the lowpass to beef up the "DAC" current, or a series pass transistor(s) if you can live with the junction drop...

Comment: Got it. Thank you guys

Comment: read up on sigma-delta ADC's and Sinc3 fiters, especially how they are done in analogue

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way: you have PWM output that goes into a low-pass filter, which goes into buffer. The higher the frequency of pwm, the better the same RC-filter will smoothen out the line.

You can also increase R or C, but doing so will slow down voltage change response time. Find the sweet spot where you can change DAC output quickly enough while filtering good enough. And your op-amp better be rail-to-rail. Make sure to check out op amp's offset voltage to see the minimum output voltage it can give, it can be uV or even some mV even for rail-to-rail.

As a downside - that need to filter out square wave into constant voltage. Check RC-filter for 1MHz, see the rejection ratio you want, probably around 40db, but if 60db is not a problem in terms of parts, it's up to you, of course.

Anyone add/modify?

[image]

Comment: Using a delta-sigma modulated output instead of simple PWM gives a much better noise performance. And it is quite easy to do in FPGA-logic!